# back button in IE7 on window.open?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I have a window that is created via window.open.
When the window is created, we turn off the address bar (location=no).
In IE6 this left the forward and back buttons active. The MSDN actually notes that this behaviour has changed for IE7 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651(VS.85).aspx ).

> The Back, Forward, and Stop commands are now located in the Navigation bar. Prior to Internet Explorer 7 navigation commands were located in the toolbar.

So in IE6, we had forward and back buttons, but no address bar.
In IE7 we have no address bar *and* no forward or back buttons.

Does anyone know of a way to get the forward and back buttons to show in IE7, but not have the address bar?

(I know this is a crazy request, but we have users screaming for it since we upgraded to IE7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're desperate you could fake it with a fake toolbar and/or button in your page and the `history.back()` javascript action. Otherwise you'll just have to settle for not hiding the address bar I guess.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<img src="/images/back.png" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:10px" onclick="history.back()">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Guess I was hoping somebody had some "magic" solution. Thanks :)